# Evaluating a contour integral

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

**Question:**
Evalate the following integral where $\Gamma: \lvert z+i \rvert = \frac{1}{25}$

$$\int_{\Gamma}\frac{1}{z^2-2}+\frac{z}{z-5} \ dz$$

**My attempt:**

$\Gamma$ is a closed curve and also no singularity exists (as $z=\sqrt{2},-\sqrt{2},5$ are not in the radius of $\Gamma$) in the closed curve $\Gamma$ therefore by the Cauchy-Goursat Theorem this integral is = 0.

Is this correct?

Comment: It looks just fine to me. +1

Comment: You have that $\Gamma=\partial D$, where $D=\{z:|z+i|\leq\frac{1}{25}\}$. The reason why the integral is $0$ is that the singularities are not in $D$. Infact you have that the function in the integral is a closed form on $D$ and $D$ is simply connected.